# Attaching click event listener in onclick immediately calls that event listener

Tags: javascript, events

I am attaching a `click` event listener to the `document` after the user clicks on a specific element on the page. However, this event listener is immediately called after the `onclick` function is called which is undesirable. It seems to be using the same click event for both `onclick` and the just added `document` `click` listener.

How can I ensure the event listener I add to the document does not get called until the next click occurs?

```
document.getElementById('someID').onclick = function(e) {
    document.addEventListener('click', myDocClickListener);
    return false; //handled click
}

function myDocClickListener(e) {
    //...
    //should only be called for future clicks not the one that just occurred in the above function
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `document.addEventListener('click', myDocClickListener());`? The `()` after the function name will call it immediately instead of adding it as a listener.

Comment: Because you bind the click event to the whole (document object) page. So any click on any element on the page will trigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of event bubbling. You need to stop the bubbling in your handler:

```
document.getElementById('someID').onclick = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    document.addEventListener('click', myDocClickListener);
    return false; //handled click
};
```

You will probably also need to keep track of whether you have attached the handler yet, so you don't end up attaching it twice if `someID` is clicked twice.

And unless this handler is on an `a` element, you don't really need to return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

JLRishe's answer is correct, but if you don't want to do `stopPropagation` for some reason, you can add event listener in the next event loop:

```
document.getElementById('someID').onclick = function(e) {
    setTimeout(
      () => document.addEventListener(
        'click',
        myDocClickListener
      ),
      0
    );
    return false; // only needed for <a> 
};
```